# Hexo blog title won't change after updating _config.yml

Tags: blogs, hexo

I keep a `source` branch for writing posts, and publish to `master` branch.

I thought that I could modify the `title` of my Hexo-based blog through `_config.yml`. However, after updating the title field, and running `hexo deploy`, the title stays the same in my source branch when I check it at `localhost:4000`. It only updates when I `git checkout master` and refresh.

The remote site updates without issues.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexo has `db.json` for file caching. Please delete `db.json` before `hexo generate` command.

You can delete `db.json` using by `hexo clean` command. If you won't delete `public` folder every time for some reason you should not use `hexo clean`. Because, this command delete `public` folder also.

> https://hexo.io/docs/commands.html#clean